# Iterate over unknown xml nodes

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

Let's say I have something like the XML below, but in my case I don't know the structure of XML:

```
<catalog>
  <cd>
    <title>Empire Burlesque</title>
    <artist>Bob Dylan</artist>
    <country>USA</country>
    <company>Columbia</company>
    <price>10.90</price>
    <year>1985</year>
  </cd>
  <cd>
    <title>Hide your heart</title>
    <artist>Bonnie Tyler</artist>
    <country>UK</country>
    <company>CBS Records</company>
    <price>9.90</price>
    <year>1988</year>
  </cd>
  <cd>
    <title>Greatest Hits</title>
    <artist>Dolly Parton</artist>
    <country>USA</country>
    <company>RCA</company>
    <price>9.90</price>
    <year>1982</year>
  </cd>
</catalog>
```

Wanted something that iterates over the nodes and print that node:

```
<xsl:template match="/*[count(descendant::*) > 0]">
    <xsl:for-each select="parent">
        <xsl:call-template name="generateClass">
            <xsl:with-param name="className" select="name(.)"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Assuming that i dont know the xml structure i want to create a xsl file that can iterate over the nodes and print all those nodes

Comment: Showing us code that doesn't work isn't a very good way of explaining your requirement. What output do you want to produce, given your sample input?

Comment: im creating a plugin for android studio to generate pojo class from xml using xsl, so i can receive any type of xml text and produce the corresponding java pojo class.

Comment: I would respectfully suggest that you are attempting something much too ambitious given your current level of knowledge. With SO we can take you one small step up your learning curve at a time; we can't take you all the way from the bottom to the top in one question.

Comment: What i want is an exemple ilustrating the use of xpath in xsl that iterates over all the unknown nodes

Comment: You seem to know `descendant::*` to find all descendant elements without using any element name so if you want to process all unknown elements in your document then use that path `descendant::*` or `//*`.